# Applying a Savitzky-Golay filter using OEEL with Google API

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, google-earth-engine-python-api, smoothing

I've been writing a code based on instructions from Geo for Good 2022: Time Series Processing Using Google Earth Engine- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ncb5_zbvnaU.

Specifically, after creating a regularized NDVI timeseries, I'm having issues using oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(...) within a Python script.

This is my current code:

```
!pip install oeel
import geemap

oeel=geemap.requireJS()
order=3
millis = 13 * (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
maxdif_filter = ee.Filter.maxDifference(
    difference=millis,
    leftField='system:time_start',
    rightField='system:time_start')
def function(infromedImage,estimationImage):
  return infromedImage.get('system:time_start').subtract(estimationImage.get('system:time_start'))
distanceFunction=function

# Apply Savitzky-Golay filter using OEEL
filtered_col=oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(interpolated_col,
                                                      maxdif_filter,
                                                      distanceFunction,
                                                      order)
```

It seems the distance function variables (infromedImage and estimationImage) aren't defined, but this is how they appear within the video and source code found at GitHub.

Do you have any thoughts?